# how to pass certain id to component using array method in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

1. I want to pass posts that match certain id.
2. How can I return certain components that satisfy my condition. The condition will return Post component if `post._id === user.id`

```js
post?.filter((post, id) => {
    return <Post key={id} data={post} id={id} 
    location='profilepage' handleDelete={handleDelete} />
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const filteredPost = posts.filter((post) => post.id === user.id));
```

Now using the filteredPost you can map the component

Comment: is it possible to do this in one iteration? if so can you update your code?

Comment: @MohammedShahed I did it in one iteration.

Comment: To render filtered elements you need another iteration.

Comment: @MohammedShahed No, as i wrote in my answer you can just map and return null in case you don't want to show something, take a look at my answer and read the exmplanation (including comments)

Answer (score 0):

The `filter` method doesn't change the elements inside an array, it just returns the same array with or without certain elements based on condition. What you want instead is to `map` your `post` variable and return a post for each `post` data.

That's the explanation:

```
// I renamed post in posts just to clarify the code
posts?.map((post, id) =>
    post._id === user.id
        ? <Post key={id} data={post} id={id} location="profilepage" handleDelete={handleDelete} />
        : null // If you return null React won't show it
)
```

Anyway, the `id` param isn't the id, it's just the index of the element inside the array (eg: 0, 1, 2, etc...)

Comment: it will render extra post components with undefined values.

Comment: No, it will render only components that match the condition and null otherwise, but as i said null is not rendered by react. If you haven't even tried don't comment

Answer (score 0):

Filter method will only give you filtered but to render it you need a render method its should be done by a function..

```
const getPost = ()=>(
  post?.map((post, id) => {
   post.id === user.id && return <Post key={id} data={post} id={id} location='profilepage' handleDelete={handleDelete} />
  })).filter(boolean)
```

In render method call finction

```
return (
{getPost()}
)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a good use case for `filter` and `includes`:

```js
const posts = [
{id: 1, name: "first"},
{id: 2, name: "second"},
{id: 3, name: "third post"}
]

const wantedPostIds = [1, 3]

console.log(posts.filter(post => wantedPostIds.includes(post.id)))
```

Comment: This doesn't event answer OG's question and anyway you're overcomplicating it since the question clearly says that the only wanted id is the user id